# how to perform yum downgrade on redhat 7

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

how to perform yum downgrade on redhat 7

for example , we want to downgrade the ambari-agent  pkg

```
yum history
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    32 | -y upgrade ambari-agent  | 2018-03-20 06:10 | Update         |    1 EE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply downgrade by undoing the latest upgrade (in this case 32):

```
yum history undo 32
```